# Node JS dispatch Cannot GET error

Tags: node.js, dispatch

I'm trying to use dispatch but when I do a test in the broswer (http://127.0.0.1/user) I get the following message

> Cannot GET /user/

what am I doing wrong?

> 127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 14 May 2012 17:40:13 GMT] "GET /user/ HTTP/1.0" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"

http://www.something.com/api/ping -> works fine

My nginx config file has this entry also.

```
location /user/ {
      proxy_pass http://www.something.com:8181;
}
```

Any have any suggestions how I can get dispatcher working?

```
var dispatch   = require('connect')

function init() {
   var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || process.env.PORT || parseInt( process.argv[2], 10 )
   var staticFolder = __dirname + '/../site/public'

   console.log('port='+port+' static='+staticFolder)

   var server = connect.createServer(
   connect.logger(),
   connect.bodyParser(),
   connect.cookieParser(),
   connect.query(),
   connect.session({secret: config.secret}),

   dispatch({
            '/user': {
                     GET: api.get_user,
                     '/socialmsg/:when': {
                           POST: api.social_msg
                     }
             }
    }),

function(req,res,next){
  if( 0 === req.url.indexOf('/api/ping') ) {
    console.log(req.url+': '+JSON.stringify(req.query))
    res.writeHead(200)
    res.end( JSON.stringify({ok:true,time:new Date()}) )
  }
  else next();
},

 connect.static( staticFolder )
 )

 server.listen( port )
 }
```

Comment: You got quite a few issues with your code unless there is more to it. For instance, you have set dispatch = require('connect'), but then use the variable "connect" instead of "dispatch" everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/senchalabs/connect, I would significantly refactor your code to make it more readable and more obvious as to what went wrong. In short, I don't believe the static directory seem to be configured as desired. I have not found a createServer() method as per the Connect module (ExpressJS and http/https modules have it though), especially one with 8 parameters as you've provided.

That said, I would stick the documentation's convention as follows:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    http = require('http');

var staticFolder = __dirname + '/../sites/public';

var server = http.createServer(
    connect
        .use(connect.static(staticFolder))
        .use(connect.logger)
        .use(connect.bodyParser)
        // etc for each of the 'connect.' middleware you are using above
        .use(function (req, res) {
            // Request handling here
        });
);

server.listen(8181);
```

In the empty function (req, res) {} you would want to put all the stuff you have for api/ping as well as the equivalents for the /user request.

In your question you provided the 'connect.static()' as an argument for createServer() (i.e. connect.createServer(connect.static)) as opposed to an argument for connect.use(), the middleware handling function in the module.